# SASS - Inspector shows wrong source

Tags: css, sass

I am working with Gulp + SASS. The problem that I sometimes have is that the (Firefox) inspector shows the wrong *.scss source (see image). Any idea what goes wrong here? In this example the Inspector says that the definition is in "pages.scss" but it is in "header.scss". This is a problem for me. I have this problem in Chrome and Internet Explorer, too.

Here the sourcemaps code:

```
 gulp.task('styles', function () {
gulp.src( styleSRC )
.pipe( sourcemaps.init() )
.pipe( sass( {
  errLogToConsole: true,
  outputStyle: 'compact',
  //outputStyle: 'compressed',
  // outputStyle: 'nested',
  // outputStyle: 'expanded',
  precision: 10
} ) )
.on('error', console.error.bind(console))
.pipe( sourcemaps.write( { includeContent: false } ) )
.pipe( sourcemaps.init( { loadMaps: true } ) )
.pipe( autoprefixer( AUTOPREFIXER_BROWSERS ) )

.pipe( sourcemaps.write ( styleDestination ) )
.pipe( lineec() ) // Consistent Line Endings for non UNIX systems.
.pipe( gulp.dest( styleDestination ) )

.pipe( filter( '**/*.css' ) ) // Filtering stream to only css files
.pipe( mmq( { log: true } ) ) // Merge Media Queries only for .min.css version.

.pipe( browserSync.stream() ) // Reloads style.css if that is enqueued.

.pipe( rename( { suffix: '.min' } ) )
.pipe( minifycss( {
  maxLineLen: 10
}))
.pipe( lineec() ) // Consistent Line Endings for non UNIX systems.
.pipe( gulp.dest( styleDestination ) )

.pipe( filter( '**/*.css' ) ) // Filtering stream to only css files
.pipe( browserSync.stream() )// Reloads style.min.css if that is enqueued.
.pipe( notify( { message: 'TASK: "styles" Completed! ', onLast: true } ) )
});
```

[image]

Comment: Are you using gulp-sourcemaps?  If not, you should be. https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-sourcemaps

Comment: I am using gulp-sourcemaps.